# Open TK determine sphere (quadstrips) normals?

Tags: vb.net, opengl, vector, opentk

**Introduction**

I am somewhat new to using Open GL / Open TK. I have learned how to draw basic shapes, use matrices, lighting, shadowing, etc.  I have a function that draws a sphere:

```
Private Sub drawSphere(r As Double, lats As Integer, longs As Integer)
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    For i = 0 To lats
        Dim lat0 As Double = PI * (-0.5 + CDbl(i - 1) / lats)
        Dim z0 As Double = Sin(lat0)
        Dim zr0 As Double = Cos(lat0)

        Dim lat1 As Double = PI * (-0.5 + CDbl(i) / lats)
        Dim z1 As Double = Sin(lat1)
        Dim zr1 As Double = Cos(lat1)

        GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.QuadStrip)
        For j = 0 To longs
            Dim lng As Double = 2 * PI * CDbl(j - 1) / longs
            Dim x As Double = Cos(lng)
            Dim y As Double = Sin(lng)

            GL.Normal3(x * zr0 * r, y * zr0 * r, z0 * r)
            GL.Vertex3(x * zr0 * r, y * zr0 * r, z0 * r)
            GL.Normal3(x * zr1 * r, y * zr1 * r, z1 * r)
            GL.Vertex3(x * zr1 * r, y * zr1 * r, z1 * r)
        Next
        GL.End()
    Next
End Sub
```

I have other code that sets up the lights. I know the other code works because I have a separate function for drawing an STL object:

```
 Dim texture As UInteger() = New UInteger(0) {}
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    If stl_table.Items.Count > 0 Then
        find_center_of_part()



        GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Triangles)
        GL.Color3(part_color.R, part_color.G, part_color.B)




        Do Until i + 4 >= stl_table.Items.Count
            GL.Normal3(Convert.ToSingle(stl_table.Items.Item(i).SubItems(0).Text), Convert.ToSingle(stl_table.Items.Item(i).SubItems(1).Text), Convert.ToSingle(stl_table.Items.Item(i).SubItems(2).Text))
            GL.Vertex3(stl_table.Items.Item(i + 1).SubItems(0).Text - avgx, stl_table.Items.Item(i + 1).SubItems(1).Text - avgy, stl_table.Items.Item(i + 1).SubItems(2).Text - avgz)
            GL.Vertex3(stl_table.Items.Item(i + 2).SubItems(0).Text - avgx, stl_table.Items.Item(i + 2).SubItems(1).Text - avgy, stl_table.Items.Item(i + 2).SubItems(2).Text - avgz)
            GL.Vertex3(stl_table.Items.Item(i + 3).SubItems(0).Text - avgx, stl_table.Items.Item(i + 3).SubItems(1).Text - avgy, stl_table.Items.Item(i + 3).SubItems(2).Text - avgz)
            i = i + 4
        Loop
        GL.End()

    End If
```

This second function basically imports a CAD STL file and draws it as triangles. The normal vectors are simply an input from the CAD file (so they are already computed). This method's lighting works perfectly fine which makes me know my lighting code is correct.

**Problem**

The problem is that my sphere is not getting light correctly. I know through testing that this is due to my normal vectors.

With the current code, my sphere looks like this:

[image]

There is a "spot" of light which makes me think that is simply one of the quadstrips having the normal correct.

Does anybody have any suggestions on setting up the normal vectors correctly inside my function? Also before anybody suggests it, I can't use GLU or GLUT for what I am trying to accomplish, which is why I need the sphere function.

Comment: I haven't looked through your math but have you tried drawing the normals?  I usually set up some helpers to draw normals and tangent vectors so you can visualize what's wrong.

Comment: I assume you want your normals to be, well, normal vectors. Try not multiplying by r for your Normal3 calls?

Comment: @RobertRouhani I tried not multiplying by r but still same result as above:                 GL.Normal3(x * zr0, y * zr0, z0)
                GL.Vertex3(x * zr0 * r, y * zr0 * r, z0 * r)
                GL.Normal3(x * zr1, y * zr1, z1)
                GL.Vertex3(x * zr1 * r, y * zr1 * r, z1 * r)